# How to use Facebook SDK with android.app.Fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to follow the samples of Facebook SDK from developers.facebook.com site.
However, what I know is it's Facebook SDK is working with Activity and android.support.v4.app.Fragment only.

Now in my application I'm using android.app.Fragment with all Fragments in my project and I don't really care about support to older version of Android.

Question is **(in case I really need to use Facebook SDK with Fragment (means I don't use it with Activity)**

- **How can I use it with android.app.Fragment?**

if there's no possible way for first question

- **How can I make android.support.v4.app.Fragment works with other android.app.Fragment?**

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the second question - you can't. The support library is a complete reimplementation and not just a thin wrapper.

As for the Facebook SDK, you have two options.

1) Convert the Facebook SDK to use app.Fragment by changing all relevant import statements. This is allowed by the license and should mostly work but now you're maintaining a fork and that's not good.

2) Convert in a similar way your own code; you won't be able to get away with just imports but it's not a hard conversion... Whether you need the backwards support is irrelevant, you're already maintaining your app, so it doesn't add to your longterm technical debt.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Just to confirm my understanding. You mean 1.I have to change import of all Facebook SDK by myself or 2. I have to change all of my Fragments to android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Am I understand it correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The Facebook SDK is open source and licensed permissively. However, the burden to maintain this version of the SDK falls on you. In essence, every time Facebook update the SDK, you'd have to redo the process. It's easier to just change your own app (it's mostly a find/replace job, really).

Comment: There is a closed PR in the repo regarding this: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/pull/369

Answer (score 0):

Now the login button has two methods: setFragment(final android.app.Fragment fragment) and setFragment(final setFragment(final Fragment fragment)Fragment fragment)

Comment: This looks kinda confusing; the second method signature looks completely broken. I guess you fix that ...